# Converting dates in SAS

Tags: date, sas

I'm quite new to SAS programming and I'm struggling with dates in it.

I have a dataset in SAS where dates are written in this format `16NOV2007:00:00:00` and I need to convert it do this format `dd/mm/yyyy`

Can anyone help in that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the following example

- `datetime_str` is your original datetime, as a string (if it's **not** a string then all you need is the `datepart()` function and a proper format).
- `sasdate` is the date part of `datetime_str` and is stored as a SAS date (which is numeric) but given a `ddmmyy` format.
- `date_str` (which might not be
  needed in your case) is a re-writing of the `sasdate` into a string
  variable, using the same `ddmmyy` format as before.

### SAS Code

```
data dates;
  format datetime_str $20. 
         sasdate ddmmyys10.
         date_str $10.;
  datetime_str = "16NOV2007:00:00:00";
  sasdate = datepart(input(datetime_str, datetime18.));
  date_str = put(sasdate, ddmmyy10.);
run;
```

### Results

```
datetime_str         sasdate      date_str 
16NOV2007:00:00:00   16/11/2007   16/11/2007
```